# How to enable all the features of instagram in flutter instagram clone App like showing feeds on the other users interests, likes and what they follow

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, instagram

I have fixed showing the feeds and posts created or posted by others and similarly able to post , comment , like and able to create  my profile, edit my profile details etc.

I am following the following code link
[code link](https://github.com/RivaanRanawat/instagram-flutter-clone) .

I have  created my own firebase storage, firebase authentications, Cloud firestore and have changed app package name etc.

I want to know  How to enable just like the Original Instagram App Features  like

Showing the feeds  or posts  which that particular user likes very much, follows more, same hobbies, interests  etc.   ( Whole Insta features)  How to achieve this type of Algorithm or logic.

Is it possible by using own firebase or firestore or Firebase cloud functions etc .Which method I have to follow to achieve the above features for my flutter application.

I am following the following code link
[code link](https://github.com/RivaanRanawat/instagram-flutter-clone) .

I have  created my own firebase storage, firebase authentications, Cloud firestore and have changed app package name etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with such a big company as Instagram, but I guess what you're asking for is almost impossible (reveal a enterprise algorithm, which might be super secret). On Instagram I guess they use screen tracking, likes of course, positioning, other metadata, etc... In order to get user info to show ads, publications, order the feed, stories... And surely even done with an AI.

With all this, I mean that it doesn't seem like an easy task, I mean any social media has whole teams just to sell ads, it can't be that straight forward.

A better approach to this topic would be to develop your own simple algorithm to order lists, such as feed or stories taking into account some metadata you might have used in the project, I don't know if they use hashtags, but you can start there.

If you are really interested in knowing how these algorithms work, you should do another whole research on big data and machine learning.

I know it won't be much useful, but you might get the bigger picture about this.

Greetings,
Pablo

Comment: yap machine learning would do, and i think he can try to use query too, like from the google one BigQuery

Comment: Thank you Pablo and stanly for your wise  suggestions and few details.

Can you both atleast for the timebeing just help me write simple algorithms to atleast show the feeds based on the other users interests and followings when followed and liked. Please try to help me with example flutter project.

Comment: Still looking for any good idea which can help me build instagram feeds app atleast only showing feeds which are mostly followed, liked , interested etc just like the original instagram application

Comment: Hi atleast help me with the approach ideas for development and achieving  those features i.e algorithms

Comment: Can anyone try to help me with my queries as above ?I am still waiting for the correct approach. Can some one (third party) handle our algorithm part